# Add a symbol '|' between in-paragraph footnotes using bigfoot package

Tags: footnotes, bigfoot

I would like to separate in-paragraph footnotes with a "|" mark using `bigfoot`. How can I do that?

Thanks

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{bigfoot}

\DeclareNewFootnote[plain]{A}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{B}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\footnoteB{First note}, consectetuer adipiscing elit\footnoteB{Second note}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I finally managed to do that using reledmac instead of bigfoot.